# Join shapefile and CSV file GDAL Jupyter notebook

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

I am new to GDAL, and trying to join a shapefile 'drisco.shp' and a csv file 'cluster.csv'.
Both of the file have a common attribute called 'FID'.

My GDAL installation is in an anconda env.

I have tried to run the following code:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select drisco2020.*, cluster.* from drisco2020 left join 'cluster2020.csv'.cluster2020 on drisco2020.FID = cluster2020.FID" shape_join.shp drisco2020.shp
```

but the following error is raised:

```
Cell In[37], line 1
    ogr2ogr -sql "select drisco2020.*, cluster2020.* from drisco2020 left join 'cluster2020.csv'.cluster2020 on drisco2020.FID = cluster2020.FID" shape_join.shp drisco2020.shp
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anybody know what can be wrong and how to solve the problem?

Comment: You're trying to run a command-line tool in a python interpreter. Either run it from a command prompt (i.e anaconda prompt with correct conda env activated), or use a jupyter [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-system) e.g. `!ogr2ogr etc...` in jupyter (doesn't work in normal python scripts) or use the python `subprocess` module.

Comment: did you do  `!apt update
!apt install -y gdal-bin`